# CUDA C compile error: new operator is not allowed in global function

Tags: c++, cuda, global, new-operator, delete-operator

I have the following CUDA C code. When trying to compile it, I get the following error:

> function new/delete operator is not allowed in global function.

I have been able to compile this code in the past without error. What could be the problem?

```
__global__ void kern(float *P, ... a bunch of other variables)
{
  ...
  W  = new float[M];
  ...
  delete[] W;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just now I figured out: in compilation, need to add

```
    -arch sm_30
```

to build the code for compuite capability 3.0.